# Getting error as logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,12] and labels shape [384]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am working on human activity recognition. When I run this code it works fine. `X_lstm_train.shape[1]=(5,52)` ,`X_lstm_train.shape[2] =(12,)`

```
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(6,input_shape=(X_lstm_train.shape[1],X_lstm_train.shape[2])))
lstm_model.add(Dense(16 ,activation='relu'))
lstm_model.add(Dense(12, activation='softmax'))
    
lstm_model.summary()
lstm_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I try to modify my model as CNN-LSTM, it gives me this error

```
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,12] and labels shape [384]
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_11977].
```

My code is included below and `X_train[0].shape=(5,52,1)`

```
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dropout,Dense,TimeDistributed,Conv1D,MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Reshape
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2,2), padding = 'same',activation='relu',input_shape=(X_train[0].shape)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2,2),activation='relu', padding = 'same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.001), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 50, validation_data= (X_test, y_test), verbose=1)
```